# Reproduce Php curl script in ASP.net

Tags: php, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, curl

I am a php developer, I have this few lines of php that picks an image upload from a form, sends it off to a Java servlet, wait for a response from the servlet and then executes an if...else if....else statement depending on what the servlet returns. Now I need to take a dive into ASP.net as I will need to duplicate same for my client whose portal is currently running on ASP.net.

Majorly, I just need y'all to help explain to me step by step how to:

1. Fetch an image from a form  using ASP.net
2. Save it in ASP.net as a variable.
3. How to create arrays in ASP.net
4. ASP.net equivalent of PHP curl.
5. How to use switch  and/or if...else statement in ASP.net

---

```
<?php

$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$filedata = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$bla = "xxxdddggg";
$blabla = 11;
$postfields = array("bla"=> $bla, "blabla"=> $blabla, "filedata" => "@$filedata", "filename" => $filename);
$url = "http://SomewhereContainingMyJAVAservlet";

$headers = array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data"); 

        $ch = curl_init($filename);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $guy = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $arr1 = str_split($guy);
        $returnVaal = $arr1[count($arr1)-1];
        echo $returnVaal;
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: A lot of your requirements are pretty basic ASP.NET stuff. Read some tutorials.

Comment: Every tutorial google search has to offer either has too many stories (irrelevant and ambiguous) or confusing me the more. Pls note that this is my first ever ASP.net experience, If you can point in the right direction of the BASIC tutorial, I'll be grateful.